# do two true statements always imply each other?

Tags: logic

If A is "1+1=2" and B is "apple starts with a", does $A\implies B$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are all true statements equivalent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570160/are-all-true-statements-equivalent)

Comment: In a logic system $A \implies B$ simply means $\lnot A \lor B$.   As the statement "Either $1 + 1 \ne 2$ or Apple starts with A" is certainly true (because apple *does* start with a) then, yes, the statement is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In symbolic logic, if B is true then A-> B is true no matter whether A is true or false.  So if A and B are both true then A->B and B->A are both true.

Outside of symbolic logic we often take "A implies B" to mean "A causes B".  That's whole different matter! A and B can both be true without one "causing" the other.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, yes.

This is a language thing - the word “implies,” in standard usage, usually means that the two are related causally.

But in mathematics “implies” is a funnier thing. $P\implies Q$ is true whenever $Q$ is true - you don’t even need $P$ to be true.  It is also true if both $P$ and $Q$ is false.

The only time it is false is if $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.